# Merging two handlers in one

Tags: jquery, html

I have two buttons **btn-config** and **btn-json-config** and i would like to combine their handlers in one. I have tried multiple ways but to no avail. I searched html data attributes but had no luck to find a solution.

```
<div class="btn btn-info margin-left-10" id="btn-config" data-*="configuration"><em class="fa fa-cog"></em> Configuration ..</div>

$("#btn-config").click(function () {
        var repository = $("#repositories").val();
        var connectionId = sessionStorage.getItem("connectionId");
        var branch = $("#branches").val();
        var button = "configuration";
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: { connectionId: connectionId, repositoryName: repository, branch: branch, button: button},
            url: '@Url.Action("GetCurrentConfiguration", "Home")',
            success: function (data) {

                codeMirrorEditor.setValue(data.content);
                $("#modal-code-editor").modal('show');
                $("#modal-title").html(data.title)
                setTimeout(function () {
                    codeMirrorEditor.refresh();
                }, 200);
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("Error: could not cancel running test...")
            }
        });
    });
```

and

```
<div class="btn btn-info margin-left-10" id="btn-json-config" data-*="json configuration"><em class="fa fa-cog"></em> JSon ..</div>

$("#btn-json-config").click(function () {
        var repository = $("#repositories").val();
        var connectionId = sessionStorage.getItem("connectionId");
        var branch = $("#branches").val();
        var button = "json configuration";
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: { connectionId: connectionId, repositoryName: repository, branch: branch, button: button},
            url: '@Url.Action("GetCurrentConfiguration", "Home")',
            success: function (data) {

                codeMirrorEditor.setValue(data.content);
                $("#modal-code-editor").modal('show');
                $("#modal-title").html(data.title)
                setTimeout(function () {
                    codeMirrorEditor.refresh();
                }, 200);
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("Error: could not cancel running test...")
            }
        });
    });
```

What i would like to do is have both buttons being handled by a single handler since both of them do exactly the same thing but with two different parameters.

Any help and/or pointers on where should i search is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `onclick` for both buttons and pass the string to js function:

```
<div onclick="myTest('configuration')" class="btn btn-info margin-left-10" id="btn-config" ><em class="fa fa-cog"></em> Configuration ..</div>

<div onclick=" myTest('json configuration')" class="btn btn-info margin-left-10" id="btn-json-config" ><em class="fa fa-cog"></em> JSon ..</div>

    function myTest(mydata){
        var repository = $("#repositories").val();
        var connectionId = sessionStorage.getItem("connectionId");
        var branch = $("#branches").val();
        var button = mydata;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: { connectionId: connectionId, repositoryName: repository, branch: branch, button: button},
            url: '@Url.Action("GetCurrentConfiguration", "Home")',
            success: function (data) {

                codeMirrorEditor.setValue(data.content);
                $("#modal-code-editor").modal('show');
                $("#modal-title").html(data.title)
                setTimeout(function () {
                    codeMirrorEditor.refresh();
                }, 200);
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("Error: could not cancel running test...")
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It works 95% like i want it. the only issue i get is the btn-config button gets the results of pressing the btn-json.

Comment: @Andreas Panteli I do not understand..Could your add breakpoints in browser and F12 to see whether the data is correct?

Comment: I tried running the code. the first time i press the btn-config i get the desirable results. when i try and press the button a couple of times more i get the results of the second button.

i have added break points and the data that get passed look fine

Comment: @Andreas Panteli So you mean the passed data is correct each time you click the button?I could not reproduce that, you may remove ajax and use simple `console.log(mydata)` to narrow down the error

Comment: it seems i made a mistake on my initial code. thank you very much for the help!

Comment: I recommend the approach I posted, because inline javascript is not a good practice, especially if you have CSPs.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#btn-json-config, #btn-config").click(function () {
[...]
var button = $(this).attr("data-*");
[...[
}
```

OR

```
$(".btn-info").click(function () {
[...]
var button = $(this).attr("data-*");
[...[
}
```

Comment: This is the jQ way to do it.